# how can i add an alpha channel to this image using ImageMagick

Tags: png, imagemagick-convert

I tried adding an alpha channel to this image [image: image without alpha channel] using this command

```
convert az.png -alpha set temp.png
```

The resulting temp.png still has no alpha channel.  What am I doing wrong?

The image was obtained from http://flagpedia.net/data/flags/mini/az.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default ImageMagick will "optimize" the output, removing the alpha channel if it's all-opaque, and perhaps converting it to indexed format if fewer than 256 colors are present.  You can force ImageMagick to retain the alpha channel by using "png32:" prefix on the output filename:

```
convert az.png png32:temp.png
```

or with the current ImageMagick release version 7

```
magick az.png png32:temp.png
```

resulting in

```
pngcheck *.png
OK: az.png (40x20, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced, 92.7%).
OK: temp.png (40x20, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 87.0%).
```